# how to find ranges in continuous values for use in building decision tree

Tags: tree, classification, decision-tree, continuous, mining

I am building a decision tree that uses fields with  continuous values (doubles).
how should I create the range nodes to build the tree with (finding the best ranges values)

Answer (score 0):

The standard way in growing a decision tree is to find the threshold that minimizes the (weighted) sum of either the entropies or the Gini impurities of the child nodes.

ALGLIB is a good open-source implementation to study when one wants to implement this oneself:

http://www.alglib.net/dataanalysis/decisionforest.php